# Why does a person's salutation not appear on the save account/contact page?

Tags: contact, person-accounts

When I am selecting a record for an account or contact lookup on an edit page, the person's name is displayed with the salutation. However, the salutation does not actually appear on the saved page.  Why is that?

Comment: Salesforce.com decided not to. Nobody outside of salesforce.com is probably qualified to answer that question. I'd suggest opening a case, but they'd probably just dismiss it.

Comment: Or vote for/create an idea requesting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Salesforce.com Support.   This is Out Of the Box as mentioned by sfdcfox. Cannot be fixed.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer even if you answered it yourself.